# How to use JQuery's .click function for a PHP generated table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have an AJAX call when the user enters the parameters, which the MySQL database returns a row, and shows it to the user through a table. I want to have it so that when they click a row, it calls back for the MySQL database, using a unique hash, to get the contents of the row that they clicked and show it in a div. So for instance, if there's a table like

```
JOHN | 21 | foo.com
AMY  | 29 | bar.com
```

that the MySQL database returned, the user can click on the row `John | 21 | foo.com` and get something like

```
John have been working at foo.com for 22 years...
```

on the div below the table. I've been able to work out most of it, but having the row be clickable is a bit of a challenge. Since I have Jquery, if I do something like

```
$('.dashboard_main_row').click(function(){
            alert('This is an alert');
        });
```

It doesn't work, as I assume the AJAX call is made after the page has been loaded, although it does on something like a static webpage in jsfiddle. So I have two questions:

- How would I implement this in JQuery where the rows are getting re-generated every time the user desires?
- How can I have a row be identifiable so that if they click `john` I get the contents of `john` not `amy`? (I do have a column hidden by CSS where it does show unique hashes.)

EDIT: I did try the method that the one the mod linked as "duplicate":

```
$('.dashboard_main_row').on('click', 'tr', function(){
            alert('This is an alert');
        });
```

And it doesn't work. That's why I switched to `.click()` instead.

Just for conciseness, here's my html code:

```
<table>
    <tbody id = "dashboard_tbody">
    <tr class = "dashboard_main_row">
         <td> John </td>
         /* ... */
    </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: `How would I implement this in JQuery where the rows are getting re-generated every time the user desires?` Use a delegated event handler - see the duplicate

Comment: `How can I have a row be identifiable so that if they click john I get the contents of john not amy?` Use the `this` keyword within the event handler to refer to the element which was clicked, eg. `$(this).text()`

Comment: Try assigning your event in the callback of the ajax call. What I usually do is I put the code that assigns the event in a function "initializeWhatever", which I call on the document ready event, and I call it again in the callback of the ajax call.
You can also set your event on a parent element like this, specifying to which child it must apply: $('#myparentdiv').on('click', '.dashboard_main_row', function() { /* ... */ });

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I already tried that method, doesn't work.

Comment: I can guarantee you that it does. From your edit I can see that the problem is because the selector for the delegated handler need to be a *static parent element*. In your current example `.dashboard_main_row` and the `tr` are the same thing so it won't work. As such, use this: `$('table').on('click', '.dashboard_main_row', function(){...`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Did exactly that and tried giving `table/tr` a div id, still doesn't really work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Update, I had to use `document` instead of divs or `table`. I heard selecting from `document` can be slower, but oh well.

Comment: It is, but we're talking a difference of milliseconds. I guess from that result that the `table` itself is dynamically created too?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, It's from an AJAX call. While you're on the line, if I wanted to select a specific <td> from the <tr> that I selected, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Within the `tr` click handler `$(this).find('td.whateverClassname')`. If you want to select a specific `td` in a column, `$(this).find('td:eq(0)')` where 0 is the first columns